# AWS Reserved Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, reserved-instances

I just bought a reserved EC2 instance. I can see it under the EC2 management console. But under the running instances i can't see any EC2 instance. How can i launch the reserved instance that i just bought ?[image: Reserved instances tab]

### This is the running instances tab

[image: running instances tab]

Answer (score 3):

Launch an instance that matches the same specification as the reserved instance you purchased.

Comment: Yes but i already paid for that reserved instance

Comment: But it's not defined yet - you need to do that as described above - please read our help pages, this site may not be for you.

Comment: You have affectively reserved the resources for an instance, you still need to actively start an instance for those resources to be allocated to. The purchased instance will be automatically associated with the new instance you create.

Comment: okay so i launched ec2 instance with the same specs. how can i be sure that they are linked and that i won't be charged for the ec2 instance ?